# C# regex find all numbers and round them to two decimal places

Tags: c#, regex, numbers

I'm trying to clean up a status email being sent using c#, the email contains a lot of numbers which have up to 8 or 9 decimal places. How would I find all numbers and replace them with rounded versions of themselves?

The first method I can think of is just to find them all using regex, and then just replace them one by one, but is there a way to do it using regex.replace with two patterns?

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use the MatchEvaluator parameter or Regex.Replace. It takes a delegate that chooses your replacement based on each particular match.
Something like this:

```
var data = ""

//Just a sample pattern for decimal numbers
var pattern = @"^[0-9]([.,][0-9]{1,9})?$";

var Matches = Regex.Replace(data, pattern, (m) =>
{
    //double.Parse your m.ToString in here, round it up or down, then convert it back 
    //to a string and return that
});
```

Comment: The regex would match something like 1,23.54.2,71 — perhaps not something that would occur in the OP's data, but something to call out. Depending on the current culture you'd need a more robust regex that uses the culture's decimal/group separator. Alternatively, the match evaluator could use `TryParse` on the result and if it fails return the original match, otherwise return the "processed" match. The answer would be better (IMO) if it showed some code in the MatchEvaluator rather than comments describing the approach.

Comment: You are correct, of course. I was in a bit of a hurry, and therefore provided OP with some skeleton code because I figured he really only was looking for the MatchEvaluator parameter. But thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I have successfully used this approach to simplify very long geospatial strings (GeoJSON, DBGeography and SqlGeography) to a reasonable number of decimals (6 or 7).